# K6 WebSockets Loadtest Report Confusing

Tags: javascript, k6

Just wanna ask, how to read the report generated by K6 on websockets load test

[image]

That's the report I got from the code i made like this

```
import {
  check,
  fail,
  sleep
} from "k6";
import {
  Counter,
  Rate
} from "k6/metrics";
import ws from "k6/ws";

let errorCount = new Counter("error_count");
//let errorRate = new Rate("error_rate");


export const options = {
  thresholds: {
    "error_rate": ["rate<0.2"]
  } // error rate not more than 20 percent
};




export default function () {
  

  var url = "wss://play.blabla.com";

  console.log(url);

  var params = {
    headers: {
      "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "accept-language": "id-ID,id;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
     
    }
  };


  let res;

  res = ws.connect(url, params, function(socket) {
    socket.on('open', function open() {
      console.log('connected');

      socket.setInterval(function timeout() {
        socket.ping();
        console.log("Pinging every 500 ms (setInterval test)");
      }, 500);
      });

      socket.on('ping', function () {
          console.log("PING!");
      });

      socket.on('pong', function () {
          console.log("PONG!");
      });

      socket.on('close', function() {
          console.log('disconnected');
      });
      
      socket.on('error', function(e) {
        if (e.error() != "websocket: close sent") {
          console.log('An unexpected error occured: ', e.error());
        }
      });

  });
  

  let checking = check(res, { "status is 101": r => r && r.status === 101 });

  
}
```

I dont understand on `ws_sessions` that hits 5603, but the `checks` said only 815

Can someone explain? Is this report was having a good result or bad result from the test.

Thanks a lot for your help guys!

Comment: `ws.connect()` won't return until the websocket connection is closed

Comment: @na-- so it means `ws.connect()` until it closed will count as 1 on `ws_sessions`? and how about `checks` that given by the report?

Comment: Yes about `ws_sessions`. About checks: I was saying that some of your iterations might never reach the `check()` call that will generate a metric, if the websocket session doesn't finish - it might emit its own metrics, but never reach the `check()`.

Comment: So is it good to go if I disabled the `check`? And stay with the `ws_sessions` for the result? And make my own counter for the errors?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but yes, having your own metric for the errors and keeping track of them in the error handler is probably a good idea. The current check you have will only catch errors in the initial connection attempt, I think. Might be worth to track both, depending on your use case.